# xslt remote debugging using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, xslt, remote-debugging

Does anyone know if eclipse has the capability of remote debugging xslt from a java web application.

I have seen this for netbeans

http://netbeans-xslt-debugger.java.net/

But would like it for eclipse, has anyone come across this for eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

OrangevoltXSLT for Eclipse provides XSLT support to the Eclipse platform.

See [Getting started with the Orangevolt Eclipse XSLT plug-in](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-orangevolt/index.html) at IBM developerworks.